# HTML Maximum Browser Width

Tags: html, browser, width

Is there a maximum browser width?
i have a photographers website that consists of many images next to each other. i seem to be having some issues after i hit 9000px in width... is there a limit at around 9000px?
thanks mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested with latest Firefox and Chrome, inserting a 12000x12000px image into a html file - everything was visible and fine. What browser do you user? What kind of problems you experience?

Comment: Thanks you are right. Problem with a div that wasn't overflowing properly!